# Terminate a thread and disconnect an indy client

Tags: delphi, indy10

In Delphi I have a threaded client that listens for response in a thread.
Thread is declared like:

```
TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FClient: TIdTCPClient;
    FStringResponse: string;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure DoSynch;
  public
    constructor Create(AClient: TIdTCPClient);
  end;
```

I connect using the:

```
  if not IdTCPClient1.Connected then
  begin
    // // Set the Host
    IdTCPClient1.Host := Edit1.Text;
    // // Set the port
    IdTCPClient1.Port := 65535;
    // // Connect
    IdTCPClient1.Connect;
    try
      MyThread := TMyThread.Create(IdTCPClient1);
    except
      IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
      raise;
    end;
  end;
```

I try to disconnect using:

```
if MyThread <> nil then
  begin
    MyThread.Terminate;
    // MyThread.WaitFor;
    MyThread.Free;
    MyThread := nil;
    IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
end;
```

But this disconnect code throws an exception. What's the proper way to do terminate this thread and to disconnect the client?

Comment: which exception is thrown, and where?

Comment: the TCP client is created in a different thread, this can cause problems if both threads do something with it. Maybe you can solve the problem by moving the TCP client inside the thread.

Comment: The disconnect part throws an exception about IdTCPClient1 not being connected. I've updated my question.

Comment: Debugging into TIdTCPConnection.Disconnect could help to find the reason. What is the exact exception class, EIdNotConnected? - In this case, your code writes or reads from the connection after it has been closed.

Comment: What is the thread actually doing with the client, and does the thread disconnect the client during its termination?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try reversing the order of your shutdown operations - disconnect the client before freeing the thread, rather than the opposite.  That way, any blocking socket operation inside the thread is aborted immeidately, allowing the thread to react to the termination:

```
if MyThread <> nil then
  MyThread.Terminate; 
try
  IdTCPClient1.Disconnect; 
finally
  if MyThread <> nil then
  begin
    MyThread.WaitFor; 
    MyThread.Free; 
    MyThread := nil; 
  end;
end;
```

If you are still getting an exception from `Disconnect()`, then make sure the thread is not disconnecting the client, only reading/writing from it, and wrap the `Disconnect()` in its own `try/except` block if needed.

Comment: Thanks Remy. In my thread's execute i have:  
while not Terminated do
  begin
    FResponse := FClient.IOHandler.ReadLn();
    Synchronize(DoSynch);
  end; so I guess I am doing something wrong in the first place

Comment: Disconnecting the client will cause `ReadLn()` to raise an exception inside the thread. That is normal, an you will only see it if you are running inside the debugger. Since you are not catching the exception, the thread will terminate itself (which is what you want it to do). Calling `TThread.WaitFor()` in the main thread allows `Synchronize()` to continue working, in case the thread already had data pending before you called `Disconnect()`. `Disconnect()` itself should not be raising any exception given the code you have shown.

Comment: Yep, I was running it inside the debugger. All is well now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could also override `TerminatedSet` method of the thread and disconnect there.